# Can a user with db_ddladmin elevate their privileges to db_owner

Tags: sql-server, permissions, role

I have a question about DB-level roles in SQL Server, can a user with db_ddladmin elevate their privileges to db_owner or any other role?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  As the docs say

> Members of this role can potentially elevate their privileges by
> manipulating code that may get executed under high privileges and
> their actions should be monitored.

[Database-level roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/database-level-roles?view=sql-server-ver16)

The most obvious vector is a table or DDL trigger that does the elevation and cleans up after itself.  Then you just need a way for a higher-privilege user to trigger the code.